# typescript compile error when using [key: string]

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

in my project, i got a ts compile error, then i make a simple demo:
code like this

```js
    interface ITest {
    getAddress: Function,
    [keys: string]: {
        name: string
        // [keys: string]: string //open this
     }
    }

    const person : ITest = {
    john: {
        name: "john"
    },
    getAddress: ()=>{
        //....
      }
    }
```

i works ok, but when i reopen commit line,
ts compile tells a error:

```sh
 couldn't assign () => void to { [keys: string]: string; name: string; }
```

i don't why i got this error or . but i have to use like this.

i think it's a typescript compile bug ? or [keys： string] list should be the same type?

my typescript version: 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Well, no it's not a bug. The line you uncommented forces all properties to have each property to be a string.

```
interface ITest2 {
  getAddress: {
    name: string, // this is required
    foo: int // error has to be string,
    bar: string // ok
  },
  someOther: {  // error because has no name property
    baz: string
  },
  another: {
    name:string // valid
  },
  [keys: string]: {
    name: string
    [keys: string]: string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for long time reply ...
i get some sense. `Function has its name`

so when i code like

```
const person : ITest = {
john: {
    name: "john"
},
getAddress: ()=>{
    //....
  }
}
```

i didn't get any error...

like @Eldar, `[key: string]: string` type makes any key be the same type.